# Azure Notebook VM start failed

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine

I created a notebook virtual machine for deep learning purpose. 
It worked totally fine this morning, but at some point, it failed to start. I was not able to either stop or restart for this vm and nothing happens when I refresh it.

Has anyone seen this issue before? please help!
[image]

Comment: yes, I had this as well. The service is still in preview and not fully stable yet. Try to create a new one - maybe also try a different region

Comment: @silent Would you recommend appropriate tools for deep learning in Azure? I am not simply implementing it to utilize GPU resource through Azure only, rather I need all to be smoothly connected to actualize stream processing framework with raw data incoming, and this deep learning analyzer has to be part of the whole framework, so it should be aligned with other DBs or streaming tools.

Comment: The ML notebook VMs are really mainly geared towards (deep learning) ML training. For inferencing in stream processing - if I got your use case right - you might rather want to look at something like Azure Databricks. So you would train a model e.g. with a notebook VM, export the trained model from there and then use it in Databricks for inferencing-